# Почему не запускается celery tasks

Tags: python, celery, crontab

Структура проекта -

```
-bitratebot
    -bitratebot
        -celery.py
        -settings.py
    -bot
        -tasks.py
        -models.py
        -views.py
    -bot3 
        -tasks.py
        -models.py
        -views.py
```

`Settings` файл -

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('bot.tasks', 'bot3.tasks')
```

`Celery.py` -

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'bitratebot.settings')

app = Celery('bitratebot')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
```

И сам `tasks.py`(для bot3) -

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import random
from celery.decorators import task
import json
from .models import *
import requests
from celery.task.schedules import crontab
from celery.decorators import periodic_task
import telebot


@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour=0, minutes=1))
def result_ivent():
    token = '*********'
    bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

    r = requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/')
    data = json.loads(r.text)

    btc_price = float(data[0]["price_usd"])

    user_prices = BotUser.objects.all().values_list('price_btc', flat=True)
    result = min(user_prices, key=lambda x: abs(btc_price - x))

    user = BotUser.objects.all()
    event = Event.objects.all().first()

    #if result in user.values_list('price_btc', flat=True):
        #event.winner = user.chat_id
        #event.save()

    for user in BotUser.objects.all():
        try:
            mes = 'Конкурс закончился! Самая точная ставка ' + str(result)
            bot.send_message(user.chat_id, mes)
        except:
            pass
```

так же `celery.service` -

```
[Unit]
Description=celery daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=bitratebot
Group=bitratebot
WorkingDirectory=/home/bitratebot/bitratebot/
ExecStart=/home/bitratebot/env/bin/celery -A bitratebot beat

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

и `celeryw.service` -

```
[Unit]
Description=celery daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=bitratebot
Group=bitratebot
WorkingDirectory=/home/bitratebot/bitratebot/
ExecStart=/home/bitratebot/env/bin/celery -A bitratebot worker

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Нужно чтобы в определенный день и время мой `tasks.py` исполнял задачу. но почему-то ничего не происходит. Будто не видит его, в чем может быть проблема?

UPD. `celery -A bitratebot worker -l info`

```
celery -A bitratebot worker -l info

 -------------- celery@cs174730 v4.1.0 (latentcall)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-4.4.0-103-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial 2017-12-12 16:20:42
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         bitratebot:0x7fdadd19d898
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379//
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . bot.models.send
  . bot.tasks.every_min
  . bot3.models.send

[2017-12-12 16:20:42,929: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379//
[2017-12-12 16:20:42,941: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2017-12-12 16:20:43,964: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2017-12-12 16:20:43,976: WARNING/MainProcess] /home/bitratebot/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:202: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '
[2017-12-12 16:20:43,977: INFO/MainProcess] celery@cs174730 ready.
[2017-12-12 16:21:00,018: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: bot.tasks.every_min[29bec85e-b427-4dac-b507-c8de8d874972]  
[2017-12-12 16:21:00,191: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task bot.tasks.every_min[29bec85e-b427-4dac-b507-c8de8d874972] succeeded in 0.1704310269999496s: None
```

Comment: Логи в студию..

Comment: А в `celery.py` не видно `app.autodiscover_tasks()`

Comment: @andreymal залил логи, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @andreymal почему-то попросту не видит мой таск

Comment: Ну, он откуда-то достаёт таску `bot.tasks.every_min`, которой в вашем коде не видно, значит вы что-то не договариваете, не может же он видеть несуществующую таску

Comment: в проекте есть 2 приложения. bot и bot3.
С bot все в порядке, а вот в bot3 таски не видит

Comment: Дайте полные пути всех связанных с celery файлов, включая пути к таскам рабочего бота, а то у меня в голове целостная картинка складываться не хочет

Comment: @andreymal обновил вначале темы структуру проекта, смотрите)

Comment: Неа, чё-то всё равно не складывается) Файл `bot3/__init__.py` существует?

Comment: @andreymal да, и он пустой кстати.

Comment: Ага, ему можно быть пустым. Но картина всё равно не складывается. Перезапуск beat'а не помогает?

Comment: @andreymal перезапускал , не помогло

Comment: Тогда идеи кончились :(